# How to remove corners from the button and make it hexagon?

Tags: android, button

I want to set every hexagon as a clickable button. At the moment i have a "hexagon.png" (square image with invisible corners), the problem is that the invisible corners are also clickable and when you try to click the neighbor hexagon you may click the invisible corner of the near button. Check the below image.
How can i cut the corners?
Any ideas?
[image: LAG Cleaner]

i thought about setting the button with round corners, but this doesn't solve the problem.

Here is the code i use at the moment:
**MainActivity**
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

```
private TransparentIgnoreButton buton1,buton2,buton3,buton4,buton5,buton6,buton7,buton8,buton9,buton10,buton11;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    buton1 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but1);
    buton2 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but2);
    buton3 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but3);
    buton4 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but4);
    buton5 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but5);
    buton6 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but6);
    buton7 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but7);
    buton8 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but8);
    buton9 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but9);
    buton10 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but10);
    buton11 = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.but11);
    buton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton3.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton4.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton5.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton6.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton7.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton8.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton9.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton10.setOnClickListener(this);
    buton11.setOnClickListener(this);
 }


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.but1:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder1.setTitle("buton1");
                builder1.setMessage("buton1 apasat");
                builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {
                        dialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog1 = builder1.create();
                dialog1.show();
                break;

            case R.id.but2:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder2.setTitle("buton2");
                builder2.setMessage("buton2 apasat");
                builder2.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog2, int which) {
                        dialog2.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog2 = builder2.create();
                dialog2.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but3:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder3.setTitle("buton3");
                builder3.setMessage("buton3 apasat");
                builder3.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog3, int which) {
                        dialog3.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog3 = builder3.create();
                dialog3.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but4:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder4.setTitle("buton4");
                builder4.setMessage("buton4 apasat");
                builder4.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog4, int which) {
                        dialog4.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog4 = builder4.create();
                dialog4.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but5:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder5 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder5.setTitle("buton5");
                builder5.setMessage("buton5 apasat");
                builder5.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog5, int which) {
                        dialog5.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog5 = builder5.create();
                dialog5.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but6:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder6 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder6.setTitle("buton6");
                builder6.setMessage("buton6 apasat");
                builder6.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog6, int which) {
                        dialog6.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog6 = builder6.create();
                dialog6.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but7:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder7 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder7.setTitle("buton7");
                builder7.setMessage("buton7 apasat");
                builder7.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog7, int which) {
                        dialog7.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog7 = builder7.create();
                dialog7.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but8:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder8 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder8.setTitle("buton8");
                builder8.setMessage("buton8 apasat");
                builder8.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog8, int which) {
                        dialog8.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog8 = builder8.create();
                dialog8.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but9:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder9 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder9.setTitle("buton9");
                builder9.setMessage("buton9 apasat");
                builder9.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog9, int which)  {
                        dialog9.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog9 = builder9.create();
                dialog9.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but10:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder10 = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder10.setTitle("buton10");
                builder10.setMessage("buton10 apasat");
                builder10.setPositiveButton("Ok", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog10, int which)  {
                        dialog10.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog10 = builder10.create();
                dialog10.show();
                break;
            case R.id.but11:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder11 = new      AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder11.setTitle("buton11");
                builder11.setMessage("buton11 apasat");
                builder11.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog11, int which)      {
                        dialog11.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog11 = builder11.create();
                dialog11.show();
                break; }
 }
 }
```

**activity_main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.lungu.myapplication.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3">
<com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
    android:id="@+id/but1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/hexagon" />

    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
    android:id="@+id/but2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />

    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
    android:id="@+id/but3"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />
    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
        android:id="@+id/but4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="228dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />

    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
        android:id="@+id/but5"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="228dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />

    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
    android:id="@+id/but6"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="151dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />
    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
        android:id="@+id/but7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="151dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />
    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
        android:id="@+id/but8"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />
    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
        android:id="@+id/but9"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />
    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
        android:id="@+id/but10"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="228dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />

    <com.example.lungu.myapplication.TransparentIgnoreButton
        android:id="@+id/but11"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="228dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon2" />

</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TransparentIgnoreButton.java**

    public class TransparentIgnoreButton extends Button
    {
    public TransparentIgnoreButton(Context context)
    {
    super(context);
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }
    public TransparentIgnoreButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

```
public TransparentIgnoreButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    // ignores touches on transparent background
    if (isPixelTransparent(x, y))
        return false;
    else
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

/**
 * @return true if pixel from (x,y) is transparent
 */
private boolean isPixelTransparent(int x, int y) {
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(getDrawingCache());
    int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    try {
        color = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // x or y exceed the bitmaps bounds.
        // Reverts the View's internal state from a previously set "pressed" state.
        setPressed(false);
    }

    // Ignores touches on transparent background.
    if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: add your code please

Comment: https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Comment: it's look be OK. it should be work.

Comment: did you try by setOnClickListener? i used this but just i used setOnClickListener.

Comment: can you write in the chat an example of how you did it with setOnClickListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this class in your project:

TransparentIgnoreButton:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by mehrdad on 10/27/2015.
 */
public class TransparentIgnoreButton extends Button
{
    public TransparentIgnoreButton(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

    public TransparentIgnoreButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

    public TransparentIgnoreButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        // ignores touches on transparent background
        if (isPixelTransparent(x, y))
            return false;
        else
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    /**
     * @return true if pixel from (x,y) is transparent
     */
    private boolean isPixelTransparent(int x, int y) {
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(getDrawingCache());
        int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
        try {
            color = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // x or y exceed the bitmaps bounds.
            // Reverts the View's internal state from a previously set "pressed" state.
            setPressed(false);
        }

        // Ignores touches on transparent background.
        if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

don't use `ImageView` or `ImageButton`

use this like below:

```
<"your package name".TransparentIgnoreButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img_center"
            android:background="@drawable/your pic"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and initialize in java like this:

```
private TransparentIgnoreButton imgCenter;
imgCenter = (TransparentIgnoreButton) findViewById(R.id.img_center);
```

Comment: but what if the image used for the button was resized in the Layer?

Comment: its OK you can use any size you want.

Comment: i made all that you wrote, launched the app and when i press an invisible corner of button1 that covers button2 it runs the code for both buttons

Comment: i don't understand it work perfect to me. when you press invisible corner button 1 that covers button 2 so button 2 did pressed?

Comment: lol that impossible let me know your code. add your code you used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113314/discussion-between-mehrdad-khosravi-and-george-lungu).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Imageview` you can use this library. This allow us to create custom shaped ImageView. 
You can write your code on `Imageview Onclicklistener`.

https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

check out this

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.{ClassName}
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siBorderWidth="8dp"
    app:siBorderColor="@color/darkgray"/>
```

**Attributes:**

- siBorderColor border color
- siBorderWidth border width in dp
- siBorderAlpha alpha value of the border between 0.0-1.0
- siStrokeCap border stroke cap type butt|round|square
- siStrokeJoin border stroke join type bevel|miter|round
     siSquare set width and height to the minimum of the given values true|false
- siShape a reference to an SVG. This is used by ShapeImageView, not the subclasses of it.

Comment: No, i don't want to create hexagons, i have them in a square .png and the corners are invisible. All i need is to ignore the clicks on the invisible part of the image.

Comment: Take one more button set transparency of that to 100% and put it above this with fixed height and width.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions that are coming to my mind.
From what I can see those haxagons are one image, if so the easiest solution would be to create overlay with transparent view and detecting click by calculating positions with screen width (you know aspect ratio of the image so offsets for center of each hexagon by x and y are constant calculable with this width and aspect ratio). You can detect click by circle approximation  with hexagon center. Something like this:

```
public OverlayView extends View{
....
boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
    //aproximating with circle
}
....
}
```

Same effect can be achieved via setOnTouchListener (and with this you will not have to extend View)